# How to reward amount to array player in game Bank - Player (nodejs-javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, math

I have a simple game, there will be 2 sides for the player to push the amount, the end game will have 1 side winner. Of course, the winning will receive the amount they bet (not all) <= I have a problem here, game script (code use nodejs, javascript)

- Side A: `[{id: 123, amount: "200", timebet: 11}, {id: 124, amount: "220", timebet: 12}, {id: 125, amount: "300", timebet: 13 }]`
- Side B: `[{id: 555, amount: "100", timebet: 22}, {id: 556, amount: "200", timebet: 23}, {id: 557, amount: "250", timebet: 24 }]`

End game:

- A win, B lose
- Total A bet: 720
- Total B bet: 550

Reward player A = 550 (total B bet), Cashback player A = 170

- Result reward = `[{id: 123, amount: "200"}, {id: 124, amount: "220"}, {id: 125, amount: "130" }]`
- Result cashback A = `[{id: 125, amount: "170"}]`

I was thinking a lot, but I couldn't find a solution for determining the list reward, and the list player to cashback (reward by sort time betted, anyone who bet first is rewarded in advance).
Who can help me (sorry about my English)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can follow the rules well enough to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I will try.

If you combine your to arrays first:

```
const merged = [...sideA, ...sideB];
```

then you can sort it according to timebet:

```
merged.sort((a,b) => a.timebet - b.timebet)
```

Then you have a list that haves the first element being the first bet and so on.

Now you can do whatever you want with it:

```
merged.forEach(bet => PayCashOut(bet););
```

Else please add a bit more information.

Comment: Oh bro, i will try apply to my project, I just joined nodejs. Thank for reply